# What is the Best way to show different kind of price to one user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

So i have this product with different kind of prices ( based on what user group you are ) ,there are so many options to show and process the prices in the client side but i can't tell which one is better .
 here are my thought ( any other suggestion would be a grace ) :
1- Save every price for each user group in DB and blah blah blah .
2- Have the formula and calculate in the client side ( filtering would be hard then )
3- Save one price in DB and make other out of that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be best handled by an [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) defined on your model. Without knowing the specifics of how you are calculating the price, as an example, you can do something to the effect of:

```
// Product.php
public function getPriceAttribute($value)
{
    // calculate the price based on the user's group
    switch(auth()->user()->group) {
        case 'group1':
            return $value * .90; // 10% off
            break;
        case 'group2':
            return $value * .80; // 20% off
            break;
        case 'group3':
            return $value * .70; // 30% off
            break;
        default:
            return $value; // normal price
    }
}
```

The price would then be accessible like:

```
$product->price
```

Comment: but how about saving them? above is about reaching them if im not mistaken